# VS2019 crashes after opening any Razor Page; "Razor Taghelper Provider is currently unavailable due to an internal error"

Tags: visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

Visual Studio will freeze and force restart after opening any Razor Page.
I tried reinstalling and repairing Visual Studio as well as deleting cache and temp files.
Creating a new ASP.NET Core(3.1 and 5.0) MVC Project also reproduces this problem.

Here is the stack trace for the razor taghelper:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Deserializing JSON-RPC result to type TagHelperResolutionResult failed with TypeLoadException: Field is Literal and InitOnly.
at StreamJsonRpc.JsonMessageFormatter.JsonRpcResult.GetResultT
at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsyncTResult
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask1.get_Result()    at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection1.TryInvokeAsyncTService,TResult
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

This is the crash log from windows event viewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeLoadException
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.Legacy.RazorParser.Parse(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorSourceDocument)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorSyntaxTree.Parse(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorSourceDocument, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorParserOptions)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorParsingPhase.ExecuteCore(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorCodeDocument)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorCodeDocument)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorCodeDocument)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorProjectEngine.ProcessCore(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorCodeDocument)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectEngine.ProcessDesignTime(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorProjectItem)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Razor.BackgroundParser+BackgroundThread.WorkerLoop()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: It seems the environment leads to the issue. What's your operation system version? I mean is it possible that the vs 2019 doesn't fit the OS. As you said you've reinstalled here, I'm afraid the issue comes from the client but not the project itself.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 enterprise. I should mention that vs 2019 was working fine a few days before with no major changes. But one thing which could be related is that I've been occasionally getting blue screen errors randomly with stop codes: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA and another one I think was MEMORY_MANAGEMENT